# Is an unit-cube polyhedron? What about other platonic solids?

Tags: terminology, definition, linear-programming, polyhedra, solid-geometry

**Definitions**

> According to my [linear programming course](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275744/explain-all-polyhedrons-are-convex-sets) and screenshot [here (Finnish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA4Z9.png), a polyhedron is such that it can be constrained by a finite amount of inequalities such that $$P=\{\bar x\in \mathbb R^n | A \bar x\geq \bar b\}, A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n},\bar b\in \mathbb R^m$$ and a convex function $f(x)$ must satisfy $$f(\lambda \bar x+(1-\lambda)\bar y)\leq \lambda f(\bar x)+(1-\lambda) f(\bar y) \text{,  }  \forall \bar x, \bar y, \lambda \in [0,1]$$ and a convex set $C$ is such that $$\bar x, \bar y \in C\rightarrow \lambda \bar x+(1-\lambda)\bar y\in C.$$

By [this calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dux4C.jpg), I think an unit-cube is not a polyhedron but an open half-space such as $\{x>0,y>0,z>0| x,y,z\in \mathbb R\}$ is a polyhedron. This strikes my intuition because I have earlier assumed polyhedron to be a closed geometrical object such as platonic shapes, terminology used in my geometry class but not in my linear optimization class! I want to recheck this:

> **Is an unit-cube a polyhedron? What about other platonic shapes, are they polyhedrons if they are closed? Do the definitions change between areas such as geometry and linear programming?**

Comment: Where did you get that definition of polyhedron?

Comment: @ChrisEagle added the source, it is a linear-programming course.

Comment: I can't see anything in your linked image that even tries to prove that a cube is not a polyhedron. The most you've done is fail to show that it is a polyhedron.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I thought it trivial: choose a point inside an unit cube i.e. $p_1\in C_1$ not on the border i.e. $p_1\not \in \partial C_1$. Now homotetia with some very large factor $k$ so that you have a point not inside the unit cube. Now the point is inside the polyhedra defined as the open set (referring to my writing by hand) but not inside unit-cube. Clear? You can scale the polyhedra $P$ defined as open-set with any factor $k\geq 1$ and you still have a polyhedron -- I assumed that you cannot define a closed polyhedron with this def...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit cube is delimited by six inequalities.  You have listed three:  $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$.  There are also $x \le 1, y \le 1, z \le 1$  You can get inequalities of this form by making $A = \begin {pmatrix} -1&0&0 \end {pmatrix}$ and $b=1$

Comment: You have A of the from $(3\times 1)$ and $x$ is a vector $(3\times 1)$ and $b$ a scalar? So $(3\times 1)(3\times 1) \not = 1$? I cannot understand. Do you mean $b=[1,1,1]^T$ i.e. of the form $(3\times 1)$? Or do you mean $A$ as $(1\times 3)$?

Comment: You are right $A$ should be $1 \times 3$

Comment: Could you clarify how you define $-x_2\geq -1$ and $-x_3\geq -1$? Please, see how I tried your method in the answer.

Comment: Actually, I think I have proved that an unit-cube is a polyhedron already with the inequalities in the form $Ax\leq b$ with $-1\leq -x_1$, $-1\leq -x_2$, $-1\leq -x_3$, $0\leq x_1$, $0\leq x_2$ and $0\leq x_3$ because the definition states *"a finite amount of inequalities"*. So the easiest way to show that something is a polyhedron is to show that you can define it with inequalities of the same direction? Can this be right? Or do I need to use matrix-notation or simpler method like yours or the mine with mere scalar inequalities? I preassumed that a scalar is a trivial $(1\times 1)$ matrix.

Comment: @hhh:  then for $x_2 \lt 1$ you use $A = \begin {pmatrix} 0&-1&0 \end {pmatrix}$ and $b=1$

Comment: I believe if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix then it should be something like $A = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$, and $b$ should be the $m$-dimensional column vector $\vec{b}\,' = (-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0)$, so that $A\vec{x} = A \left( \begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{smallmatrix} \right) \geq \left( \begin{smallmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ accounts for the six inequalities $0 \leq x \leq 1\,$, $\ 0 \leq y \leq 1$, and $\ 0 \leq z \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot yet fully understand Ross Millikan's method but below how I would show that an unit-cube is a polyhedron. I showed that it is possible to have a finite amount of $Ax\geq b$-form inequalities for an unit-cube.

[image]

As for the general question about other platonic solids, a similar method should prove them to be polyhedrons. I think the definitions are the same between linear programming and geometry -- the earlier definition is just succint formalism, a bit tricky one.

Comment: Note that you can get away with either a finite number of inequalities of the form $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{x}\geq b$ (where both $v$ and $x$ are vectors and $b$ is a scalar) or a _single_ inequality of the form $A\cdot\vec{x}\geq \vec{b}$ (where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, $x$ is an $n$-vector and $b$ is an $m$-vector) - combining the two is liable to get confusing quickly.  Also, note that this definition only covers _convex_ polyhedra - you can't achieve any concave polyhedron in this way.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Hey! +1 I think you are able to answer my question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/275747/5902): I have been wondering this problem a long time -- good point that the polyhedron must be convex, thinking...there are also something-called orthogonal polyhedrons that are not convex at all (confusing this even more). I am not sure whether different sources use just different definitions, trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of polyhedron,  "A polyhedron is a close solid having certain no. of (regular or irregular) polygonal (flat) faces such that the sum of the solid angles subtended by all its faces at any point exactly inside it must be $4\pi$ Ste-radian". Mathematically, it is given as $$\bbox [4pt, border: 1px solid blue;] {\omega _{total}=4\pi \space sr} $$

Where, $\omega _{total} \space \to$ total solid angle subtended by all the faces of any existing polyhedron at any arbitrary point inside it.
This definition is valid for all the regular and irregular polyhedrons having polygonal faces either regular or irregular or both.

To prove that a cube is a polyhedron, let's consider the center of the cube as an internal point (we can select any other point as well) only for simplification of calculations,

Now, let a be the edge length of a cube then we know that each face of a square is at a normal distance $ \frac{a}{2} $ . Now the solid angle ($\omega$) subtended by any square of side $a$ ant any point ying at a normal distance $d$ is given as
$$\omega =4sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+4d^2}\right)$$
Above formula, for a square plane, is derived from basic formula of solid angle $\iint_Ssin\theta d \theta d \phi $
now, substituting the corresponding values in the formula, we get the solid angle subtended by each square face of the cube at its center, as follows
$$\omega =4sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+4\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2}\right)=4sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)=4\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{3} sr$$
Now, the total solid angle ($\omega _{total}$) subtended by all 6 square faces at the center of cube 
$$\omega _{total}=(no. \space of \space faces) \cdot (solid \space angle \space subtended \space by \space each \space face)=6\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=4\pi \space sr$$
Hence, the cube is a polyhedron (also called as regular hexahedron). It is also a (closed) solid.